# changing get variable using parse_url not working in php

Tags: php

I've looked at every post on SO that remotely pertains to this and I just can't figure this out. This code is taken directly from another SO post and was marked as the correct working answer:

```
$query = $_GET;
// replace parameter(s)
$query['d'] = 'new_value';
// rebuild url
$query_result = http_build_query($query);
// new link
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?<?php echo $query_result; ?>">Link</a>
```

Again, taken straight from another post. When I try this code, i change the `$_GET` to the actual URL that i want to alter. When the code gets to the `$query['d']` part, it tells me I get an `illegal string offset` and the error is the index that's specified. So then I parse the URL, and then do `parse_str($query, $output)` which in turn allows me to do `$output['d']` and THEN I can set a new value to that variable. If I echo it out, it's fine.

But then I get to the `http_build_query` line, and it tells me that it's expecting an array or object and I can't build the new URL. Here is my code:

```
$link = parse_url('https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=85GhW6CNHoSqsgXnzoD4Ag&q=coding+tutorial&btnK=Google+Search&oq=coding+tutorial', PHP_URL_QUERY);

 parse_str($link, $output);
 $output['oq'] = 'new value';

 $query_result = http_build_query($link);
echo $query_result;
```

This code yields that the `http_build_query` function wants an array or object...i guess i'm not giving it that in some way? What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: You're calling `http_build_query($link)` instead of `http_build_query($output)`

Comment: Ok, that actually worked lol. Thanks for the quick reply. Now after I echoed it in my code just now, it only prints the parameters. It doesn't actually rebuild the entire url, just the part after the "?" where the GET parameters start. How can i get it back into the full URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rebuild the full URL after modifying the query parameters, you could do this:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=85GhW6CNHoSqsgXnzoD4Ag&q=coding+tutorial&btnK=Google+Search&oq=coding+tutorial';
$link = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($link, $output);
$output['oq'] = 'new value';
echo substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '?') + 1) . http_build_query($output);
```

Output:

```
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=85GhW6CNHoSqsgXnzoD4Ag&q=coding+tutorial&btnK=Google+Search&oq=new+value
```